# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled. Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {313CF0C8-2F04-4A83-839E-075D70E89FE7}

Tags: c#, comexception, was, unhandled

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtX3c.png]

I am using the third party Library "XPression" for developing a C# project. But I am facing some problem which is shown in the screenshot image below. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: "Class is not licensed for use".   Clearly you need to call the vendor to get the license sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

The 8004112 code stands for CLASS_E_NOTLICENSED.

A nice workaround can be found [here](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2013/03/13/mscomm32-ocx-returns-error-80040112/)

Comment: That's not a workaround, it is specific to that VB6 control from Microsoft.

Comment: The post uses the MS control as an example. By following the steps and make the proper adjustments one can resolve this problem